# Windows hosted network not transmitting multicast H.264 stream

Tags: networking, windows-8.1, multicast

I am trying to have a Windows hosted network WiFi access point route a multicast stream to an associated computer.

The following is my network layout:

IP Camera --(Wired)--> Computer A --(Wireless)--> Computer B

- IP Camera: static IP 192.168.1.10/24
- Machine A (Windows 8.1): static IP 192.168.1.11/24 (Wireless AP hosted network 192.168.137.1)
- Machine B (Windows 7): DHCPv4 IP 192.168.137.251/24 from Machine A's hosted network

The IP camera is sending a H.264 multicast video stream to 224.100.1.1:5001. I am able to view the stream on Computer A using VLC when I connect to udp://@224.100.1.1. However, I'm not able to get Computer A's (Windows 8.1) SoftAP hosted network to transmit multicast H.264 video to Computer B (Windows 7).

I would expect that the Windows 8.1 hosted network softAP software would proxy IGMPv3 request and then route the multicast data appropriately. I have searched SuperUser questions to find an answer but I have not found an answer so I'm posting this.

Steps I have taken:

- I have verified with Wireshark on both ends that Computer B is sending IGMPv3 join requests to Computer A when I connect with VLC to udp://@224.100.1.1.
- I have turned off the firewall on Computer A and B to eliminate firewall issues.
- I verified that ping from Machine B to Machine A and ping Machine A from Machine B works.
- I have tried adding a multicast static route on Computer A 'route add 224.100.1.1 mask 240.0.0.0 192.168.137.1' but it says the command is invalid. Anyone know why?
- I found multicast 'netsh routing' option for  Windows Server but I have not found an equivalent option for Windows 8.1.

Any help and/or suggestions to route multicast streams across a Windows 8.1 hosted network will be appreciated.